# Где активировать код python для телеграм

Tags: python, telegram

Я написал код, все зделал. Но по видео уроку, да и везде пишут активировать код пишите python bot.py . Но где его писать?
Я только начинаю и не могу понять.

Answer (score 1):

Пишите фразу в командной строке. Для того, чтобы её открыть, нужно:

- Написать в поиске программ `cmd`
- открыть найденное приложение

Помог?

Comment: Возможно здесь вопрос именно про сервер размещения бота

Comment: @artemgh тогда пусть пишет в вопросе...